# Changing links, and iframe source with javascript

Tags: javascript

SO!!!...ok...there's a lot to this, but I've got everything working with the exception of one small detail. Firstly, I'll try to explain a little about what it is I'm trying to have achieved... on the sidebar, I have 10 links to different html files to be displayed within the iframe. the 3 "versions" buttons in the center of the page are intended to both, change the directories for those 10 links, but also edit the `<iframe src="xxx.html"/>`. It works perfectly, except for link number 10. I have not had any progress in finding what is going wrong, but the `<iframe src="xxxx.html"/>` is working with all links, except link 10.

Just to clarify, the issue is NOT with the sidenav links. As far as I can tell, all links are being modified to the correct directory when the version button is clicked. The problem is with the `<iframe src="xxx.html"/>` modification, ONLY when link 10 is the "active" link.

To clearly see the issue, you'll need to open the inspector and find the iframe element to see how the src value is changing properly when any links 1-9 are active, but the directory is not being modified correctly when link 10 is active.

The Recoded button should link `src` to ../example/recoded/xxxx.html

The Encoded button should link `src` to ../example/encoded/xxxx.html

The PNG button should link `src` to ../example/img/xxxx.png

Thanks so much for the help.

```js
//Script
/* function to add and remove active classes from clicked sidebar and versions buttons */
var selector, elems, makeActive, versBtn, btns;
selector = '.sideUL li';
elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
btns = document.getElementsByClassName('versions');

makeActive = function () {
  if(this.tagName == 'LI'){
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
      elems[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }else if(this.tagName == 'DIV'){
    for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
      btns[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
  this.classList.add('active');
};

for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
  elems[i].addEventListener('mousedown', makeActive);
}
for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
  btns[i].addEventListener('mousedown', makeActive);
}

//Start of linkChange function
/*
primaryDir is the desired target link;
firstSecondary is first search option;
secondSecondary is designated for .png version; unless .png is primaryDir value;
*/
function linkChange(vers, primaryDir, firstSecondary, secondSecondary){
  var link = '.sideUL li a';
  var htmlRef, anchor, activeLink, linkIncludesPrim, linkIncludesFirst, linkIncludesSecond, iFra, activeRef;
  htmlRef = document.querySelectorAll(link);
  activeLink = document.querySelectorAll('.sideUL .active');
  for(var i = 0; i < htmlRef.length; i++){
    anchor = htmlRef[i];
    activeRef = activeLink[0].children[0].href;
    linkIncludesPrim = anchor.href.includes(primaryDir);
    linkIncludesFirst = anchor.href.includes(firstSecondary);
    linkIncludesSecond = anchor.href.includes(secondSecondary);
    iFra = document.getElementById('iFCont');
    if(vers === 'clean'){
      if(linkIncludesPrim == true){
        console.log("Alread Linked.");
      }else if(linkIncludesFirst == true){
        anchor.href = anchor.href.replace(firstSecondary, primaryDir);
        iFra.src = activeRef;
        console.log(anchor.href);
      }else if(linkIncludesSecond == true){
        anchor.href = anchor.href.replace(secondSecondary, primaryDir);
        anchor.href = anchor.href.replace(".png", ".html");
        iFra.src = activeRef;
        iFra.src = iFra.src.replace(".png", ".html");
        console.log(anchor.href);
      }else{
        console.log("Error, no return.");
      }
    }else if(vers === 'encode'){
      if(linkIncludesPrim == true){
        console.log("Alread Linked.");
      }else if(linkIncludesFirst == true){
        anchor.href = anchor.href.replace(firstSecondary, primaryDir);
        iFra.src = activeRef;
        console.log(anchor.href);
      }else if(linkIncludesSecond == true){
        anchor.href = anchor.href.replace(secondSecondary, primaryDir);
        anchor.href = anchor.href.replace(".png", ".html");
        iFra.src = activeRef;
        iFra.src = iFra.src.replace(".png", ".html");
        console.log(anchor.href);
      }else{
        console.log("Error, no return.");
      }
    }else if(vers === 'png'){
      if(linkIncludesPrim == true){
        console.log("Alread Linked.");
      }else if(linkIncludesFirst == true){
        anchor.href = anchor.href.replace(firstSecondary, primaryDir);
        anchor.href = anchor.href.replace(".html", ".png");
        iFra.src = activeRef;
        iFra.src = iFra.src.replace(".html", ".png");
        console.log(anchor.href);
      }else if(linkIncludesSecond == true){
        anchor.href = anchor.href.replace(secondSecondary, primaryDir);
        anchor.href = anchor.href.replace(".html", ".png");
        iFra.src = activeRef;
        iFra.src = iFra.src.replace(".html", ".png");
        console.log(anchor.href);
      }else{
        console.log("Error, no return.");
      }
    }
  }
}

function changeFormat(ver){
  var firstTxt = document.getElementById("firstStat");
  var verText;
  if(ver === "reCode"){
    linkChange('clean', "example/Recoded", "example/Encoded", "example/Img");
  }else if(ver === 'enCode'){
    linkChange('encode', "example/Encoded", "example/Recoded", "example/Img");
  }else if(ver === 'img'){
    linkChange('png', "example/Img", "example/Recoded", "example/Encoded");
  }
}

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "200px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
   
body {
  font-family: Georgia; 
  color: #444; 
}

.frame{
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

div.frame iframe{
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.sidenav li{
  border-bottom: none;
}

.sidenav{
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #666;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.sidenav .closebtn{
  right: 0;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.sidenav a{
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover{
  background-color: #222;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.sideNavLogo{
  position: fixed;
  left: 1%;
  bottom: 50%;
  width: 105px;
}

.versions{
  color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  min-width: 170px;
  display:block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1% 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 1%;
  background-color: #666666;
}

.versions:hover{
  background-color: #222222;
}

.active{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="versions" onclick="changeFormat('reCode')">
  <p class="enlarge">Recoded version</p>
 </div>
 <div class="versions active" onclick="changeFormat('enCode')">
  <p class="enlarge">Encoded version</p>
 </div>
 <div class="versions" onclick="changeFormat('img')">
  <p class="enlarge">PNG version</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="frame">
 <iframe src="./example/Encoded/20180112_example1.html" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" height="2450" width="620" name="content" id="iFCont">Sorry, your browser doesn't support inline iframes.</iframe>
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
 <a href="#" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
 <ul class="sideUL">
  <li class="active">
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example1.html" target="content">Example 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example2.html" target="content">Example 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example3.html" target="content">Example 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example4.html" target="content">Example 4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example5.html" target="content">Example 5</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example6.html" target="content">Example 6</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example7.html" target="content">Example 7</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example8.html" target="content">Example 8</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example9.html" target="content">Example 9</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example10.html" target="content">Example 10</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="sideNavLogo">
 <div style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Links</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does anybody have any ideas why the source of the iframe is't changing properly when the example 10 link is active? I just don't understand why it works with links 1 through 9, but breaks with link 10, given that all 10 links run the same script..

Comment: Again, to summarize, open the sidenav, and click any link. The default version is encoded. The versions buttons recoded, encoded, and png change the directory of all 10 links properly. They also change the source directory of the iframe. This function works with links 1 through 9, but it does not work with link 10. Please help, I'm lost as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged the error. All edits were to the `linkChange` function. `iFra.src =` was moved after the `for` loop along with a few other variable definitions. Shaved off a few lines in doing so. Stay smart out there.

```js
//Script
/* function to add and remove active classes from clicked sidebar and versions buttons */
var selector, elems, makeActive, versBtn, btns;
selector = '.sideUL li';
elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
btns = document.getElementsByClassName('versions');

makeActive = function () {
  if(this.tagName == 'LI'){
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
      elems[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }else if(this.tagName == 'DIV'){
    for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
      btns[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
  this.classList.add('active');
};

for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
  elems[i].addEventListener('mousedown', makeActive);
}
for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
  btns[i].addEventListener('mousedown', makeActive);
}

//Start of linkChange function
/*
primaryDir is the desired target link;
firstSecondary is first search option;
secondSecondary is designated for .png version; unless .png is primaryDir value;
*/
function linkChange(vers, primaryDir, firstSecondary, secondSecondary){
  var htmlRef, dir, activeLink, linkIncludesPrim, linkIncludesFirst, linkIncludesSecond, iFra, activeRef;
  htmlRef = document.querySelectorAll('.sideUL li a');
  activeLink = document.querySelectorAll('.sideUL .active');
  for(var i = 0; i < htmlRef.length; i++){
    dir = htmlRef[i];
    linkIncludesPrim = dir.href.includes(primaryDir);
    linkIncludesFirst = dir.href.includes(firstSecondary);
    linkIncludesSecond = dir.href.includes(secondSecondary);
    if(vers == 'clean'){
      if(linkIncludesPrim == true){
        console.log("Alread Linked.");
      }else if(linkIncludesFirst == true){
        dir.href = dir.href.replace(firstSecondary, primaryDir);
        console.log(dir.href);
      }else if(linkIncludesSecond == true){
        dir.href = dir.href.replace(secondSecondary, primaryDir);
        dir.href = dir.href.replace(".png", ".html");
        console.log(dir.href);
      }else{
        console.log("Error, no return.");
      }
    }else if(vers == 'encode'){
      if(linkIncludesPrim == true){
        console.log("Alread Linked.");
      }else if(linkIncludesFirst == true){
        dir.href = dir.href.replace(firstSecondary, primaryDir);
        console.log(dir.href);
      }else if(linkIncludesSecond == true){
        dir.href = dir.href.replace(secondSecondary, primaryDir);
        dir.href = dir.href.replace(".png", ".html");
        console.log(dir.href);
      }else{
        console.log("Error, no return.");
      }
    }else if(vers == 'png'){
      if(linkIncludesPrim == true){
        console.log("Alread Linked.");
      }else if(linkIncludesFirst == true){
        dir.href = dir.href.replace(firstSecondary, primaryDir);
        dir.href = dir.href.replace(".html", ".png");
        console.log(dir.href);
      }else if(linkIncludesSecond == true){
        dir.href = dir.href.replace(secondSecondary, primaryDir);
        dir.href = dir.href.replace(".html", ".png");
        console.log(dir.href);
      }else{
        console.log("Error, no return.");
      }
    }
  }
  iFra = document.getElementById('iFCont');
  activeRef = activeLink[0].children[0].href;
  iFra.src = activeRef;
  console.log("Frame source - " + iFra.src);
}

function changeFormat(ver){
  var firstTxt = document.getElementById("firstStat");
  var verText;
  if(ver === "reCode"){
    linkChange('clean', "example/Recoded", "example/Encoded", "example/Img");
  }else if(ver === 'enCode'){
    linkChange('encode', "example/Encoded", "example/Recoded", "example/Img");
  }else if(ver === 'img'){
    linkChange('png', "example/Img", "example/Recoded", "example/Encoded");
  }
}

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "200px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
   
body {
  font-family: Georgia; 
  color: #444; 
}

.frame{
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

div.frame iframe{
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.sidenav li{
  border-bottom: none;
}

.sidenav{
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #666;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.sidenav .closebtn{
  right: 0;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.sidenav a{
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover{
  background-color: #222;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.sideNavLogo{
  position: fixed;
  left: 1%;
  bottom: 50%;
  width: 105px;
}

.versions{
  color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  min-width: 170px;
  display:block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1% 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 1%;
  background-color: #666666;
}

.versions:hover{
  background-color: #222222;
}

.active{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="versions" onclick="changeFormat('reCode')">
  <p class="enlarge">Recoded version</p>
 </div>
 <div class="versions active" onclick="changeFormat('enCode')">
  <p class="enlarge">Encoded version</p>
 </div>
 <div class="versions" onclick="changeFormat('img')">
  <p class="enlarge">PNG version</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="frame">
 <iframe src="./example/Encoded/20180112_example1.html" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" height="2450" width="620" name="content" id="iFCont">Sorry, your browser doesn't support inline iframes.</iframe>
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
 <a href="#" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
 <ul class="sideUL">
  <li class="active">
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example1.html" target="content">Example 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example2.html" target="content">Example 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example3.html" target="content">Example 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example4.html" target="content">Example 4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example5.html" target="content">Example 5</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example6.html" target="content">Example 6</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example7.html" target="content">Example 7</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example8.html" target="content">Example 8</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example9.html" target="content">Example 9</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="./example/Encoded/20180112_example10.html" target="content">Example 10</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="sideNavLogo">
 <div style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Links</div>
</div>
```